Mapbox Navigation SDK v3 with React Native not being initialized
Hi I am using Mapbox Navigation SDK v3 with a Android in a React Native (v0.73) project.
I am stuck initializing the sdk inside a view file
class MapNavigationView(private val context: ThemedReactContext) :
...
private val navigationObserver = object : MapboxNavigationObserver {
        override fun onAttached(mapboxNavigation: MapboxNavigation) {
            sendErrorToReact("onAttached: $mapboxNavigation")
        }
        override fun onDetached(mapboxNavigation: MapboxNavigation) {
            sendErrorToReact("onDetached: $mapboxNavigation")
        }
    }
private lateinit var mapboxNavigation: MapboxNavigation
...
fun onCreate() {

        if (!MapboxNavigationApp.isSetup()) {
            sendErrorToReact("Getting setup")
            MapboxNavigationApp.setup (
                NavigationOptions.Builder(context)
                    .build()
            )
            MapboxNavigationApp.registerObserver(navigationObserver)
            sendErrorToReact(MapboxNavigationApp.current().toString())
            sendErrorToReact(MapboxNavigationApp.toString())
        }
        if(MapboxNavigationApp.current() != null){
            mapboxNavigation = MapboxNavigationApp.current()!!
        }
}

MapboxNavigationApp.current() is always null. I keep receiving the error that mapboxNaigation variable is not initialized.
Any help getting this running would be great thanks!

Ok I managed to fix this by using the lifecycle event:
private val lifecycle: Lifecycle by lazy {
    (context.currentActivity as AppCompatActivity).lifecycle
}

override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow()
    lifecycle.addObserver(object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
        override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
            sendErrorToReact("onResume")
            MapboxNavigationApp.attach(owner)
        }

        override fun onPause(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
            sendErrorToReact("onPause")
            MapboxNavigationApp.detach(owner)
        }
    })
    onCreate()
}

